# extracting innermost nested links

Tags: python, html

[image]

for the given example html page:

```html
<div class="ia-secondary-content">
  <div class="plugin_pagetree conf-macro output-inline" data-hasbody="false" data-macro-name="pagetree">
    <div class="plugin_pagetree_children_list plugin_pagetree_children_list_noleftspace">
      <div class="plugin_pagetree_children" id="children1326817570-0">
        <ul class="plugin_pagetree_children_list" id="child_ul1326817570-0">
          <li>
            <div class="plugin_pagetree_childtoggle_container">
              <a aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Expand item Topic 1" class="plugin_pagetree_childtoggle aui-icon aui-icon-small aui-iconfont-chevron-right" data-page-id="1630374642" data-tree-id="0" data-type="toggle" href="" id="plusminus1630374642-0"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="plugin_pagetree_children_content">
              <span class="plugin_pagetree_children_span" id="childrenspan1630374642-0"> <a href="#">Topic 1</a></span>
            </div>
            <div class="plugin_pagetree_children_container" id="children1630374642-0"></div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <div class="plugin_pagetree_childtoggle_container">
              <a aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Expand item Topic 2" class="plugin_pagetree_childtoggle aui-icon aui-icon-small aui-iconfont-chevron-right" data-page-id="1565544568" data-tree-id="0" data-type="toggle" href="" id="plusminus1565544568-0"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="plugin_pagetree_children_content">
              <span class="plugin_pagetree_children_span" id="childrenspan1565544568-0"> <a href="#">Topic 2</a></span>
            </div>
            <div class="plugin_pagetree_children_container" id="children1565544568-0"></div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <div class="plugin_pagetree_childtoggle_container">
              <a aria-expanded="true" aria-label="Expand item Topic 3" class="plugin_pagetree_childtoggle aui-icon aui-icon-small aui-iconfont-chevron-down" data-children-loaded="true" data-expanded="true" data-page-id="3733362288" data-tree-id="0" data-type="toggle"
                href="" id="plusminus3733362288-0"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="plugin_pagetree_children_content">
              <span class="plugin_pagetree_children_span" id="childrenspan3733362288-0"> <a href="#">Topic 3</a></span>
            </div>
            <div class="plugin_pagetree_children_container" id="children3733362288-0">
              <ul class="plugin_pagetree_children_list" id="child_ul3733362288-0">
                <li>
                  <div class="plugin_pagetree_childtoggle_container">
                    <span class="no-children icon"></span>
                  </div>
                  <div class="plugin_pagetree_children_content">
                    <span class="plugin_pagetree_children_span"> <a href="#">Subtopic 1</a></span>
                  </div>
                  <div class="plugin_pagetree_children_container"></div>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <div class="plugin_pagetree_childtoggle_container">
                    <span class="no-children icon"></span>
                  </div>
                  <div class="plugin_pagetree_children_content">
                    <span class="plugin_pagetree_children_span"> <a href="#">Subtopic 2</a></span>
                  </div>
                  <div class="plugin_pagetree_children_container"></div>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <div class="plugin_pagetree_childtoggle_container">
              <a aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Expand item Topic 4" class="plugin_pagetree_childtoggle aui-icon aui-icon-small aui-iconfont-chevron-right" data-page-id="2238798992" data-tree-id="0" data-type="toggle" href="" id="plusminus2238798992-0"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="plugin_pagetree_children_content">
              <span class="plugin_pagetree_children_span" id="childrenspan2238798992-0"> <a href="#">Topic 4</a></span>
            </div>
            <div class="plugin_pagetree_children_container" id="children2238798992-0"></div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <fieldset class="hidden">
    </fieldset>
  </div>
</div>
```

I need to extract the innermost nested links from this sort of a page tree. Given the title within which, I need to get all the links, how can I find all the innermost nested links. I want to write a python script for the same which dynamically extracts the innermost nested links of the various html pages provided. Take note that the nesting levels may not be the same.

thus for the example I should get:

```
<a href="#">Subtopic 1</a>
<a href="#">Subtopic 2</a>
```

I tried extracting all the links in the same nesting structure but it didn't work

```
# Step 1: Find the div with the given title
title = "Topic 3"
target_div = soup.find('span', class_='plugin_pagetree_children_span', text=title)

# Step 2: Extract the next div with class "plugin_pagetree_children_container"
if target_div:
    container_div = target_div.find_next_sibling('div', class_='plugin_pagetree_children_container')

    # Step 3: Extract all links within the container and print them
    if container_div:
        links = container_div.find_all('a')
        for link in links:
            print(link['href'])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC you can do:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# html_text = ... # your html code from the question

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text, "html.parser")

for a in soup.select("li li a"):
    print(a)
```

Prints:

```html
<a href="#">Subtopic 1</a>
<a href="#">Subtopic 2</a>
```

---

EDIT:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text, "html.parser")

result, tags = None, ["li", "a"]
while True:
    a = soup.select(" ".join(tags))

    if not a:
        break
    else:
        tags.insert(0, "li")
        result = a

print(result)
```

Prints:

```
[<a href="#">Subtopic 1</a>, <a href="#">Subtopic 2</a>]
```

Comment: I don't know how many list tags will it be nested under though

Comment: @RachelNegi See my edit. Just add `li` to CSS selectors until you get no tags.